# Extraction the letter "C" using a regular expression I want only cells which begin with "C" be included in the calculation and using an IF statement

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code, I want the first if statement to be true only where r[18] < 6 and for the cells in column 14 which start with "C"
I'm trying to use a regular expression to extract the first letter but unfamiliar using Regex. Can someone please assist. Thanks

````
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10D0Qa8Y6nrAgeuS0V6-GyKkQBRooMUwseRc8agi7iN4');
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("QUOTATIONS");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const prod = sh.getRange(2, 14, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  RegExp(/^C/i,prod,0);
  
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {  if(r[18] < 6 && RegExp(/^C/i,prod,0))
    sh.getRange(i + 2,33).setNumberFormat("0.#0").setValue((r[18] * r[19]) + (r[21] * r[22]) + (r[24] * r[25]) + (r[27] * r[28]) + (r[28] * r[31])+ (6 - r[18]) * 20)
    vs.forEach((r,i) => { if(r[18] >= 6)
    sh.getRange(i + 2,33).setNumberFormat("0.#0").setValue((r[18] * r[19]) + (r[21] * r[22]) + (r[24] * r[25]) + (r[27] * r[28]) + (r[28] * r[31]))
});
  }
  )}```
````

Comment: hi, you could also use [`RegExp.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to match the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just a first letter you don't even need RegExp. It can be done with `slice()` this way:

```js
var s = 'abc'

console.log(s.slice(0,1)) // output: 'a'
```

Or even:

```js
var s = 'abc'

console.log(s[0]) // output: 'a'
```

If you want RegExp it can be `string.match(/reg/)` or `/reg/.test(string)`:

```js
var s = 'abc'

if (s.match(/^a/i)) { console.log('yes') } else { console.log('no') } // yes

if (s.match(/^b/i)) { console.log('yes') } else { console.log('no') } // no

if (/^a/i.test(s)) { console.log('yes') } else { console.log('no') } // yes

if (/^b/i.test(s)) { console.log('yes') } else { console.log('no') } // no
```

Comment: Or for that matter `if( s.charAt(0) === 'C' ) {}`